# Permission denied appending passwd and shadow files to log files

Tags: linux, fedora

I created 5 new users in Fedora. However, all this has to be appended to a log file. One of the requirements for the assignment is to append */etc/passwd* and */etc/shadow* files into a log file. I am logged in as the admin in root and when I try something along the lines of:

```
/etc/passwd >> file.log
```

I get a *permission denied* message. How would I be able to post the contents of these files into my log file?

Answer (score 1):

The command:

```
/etc/passwd >> file.log
```

attempts to *execute* the `/etc/passwd` file, but `/etc/passwd` is not an executable, hence the *permission denied* error.

To redirect the *contents* of the file, you can use `cat`:

```
cat /etc/passwd >> file.log
```

(In fact, you could use any other command that reads files and outputs their contents on standard output, for example `sed '' /etc/passwd` or `awk 1 /etc/passwd`).